# Reactjs setting state of array of object issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-native

I'm new to Reactjs and I'm learning to change state properties using setState method. I have few questions regarding changing state in reactjs.

I'm building a weather web using open weather API for education purpose. I'm saving some properties inside the state so that I can pass them as props to other components. The state is as follows:

```
export default class App extends Component {
    state ={
       error: null,
       temperature: null,
       WeatherName: null,
       isLoaded: false,
       Weather5days: [{}]
}
```

I have some normal properties(e.g. temperature, isLoaded) and also array of object called Weather5days. Here I'm going to save weather data for each 5 days; data for each day will go into each array, total length of 5. I know javascript allows to declare array and object with unknown length(is that how you declare it though?), so I have declared it as above. Hence the data in Weather5days it's going to look something like this:

```
state = {
...
Weather5days = [{date: "8.21", temperature: "20"},
                {date: "8.22", temperature: "25"},
                {date: "8.23", temperature: "24"},
                ...so on
               ]
```

Now I wish to add/alter the properties of each array of Weather5days, e.g. Weather5days[0].temperature = '25' etc... I get this data from weather API as json(also in array) and assign the parsed data to the created Weather5days array object.

I did some googling and found out that I cannot directly mutate state, so I've done the following after fetching:

```
.then(json =>{
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const newItems = [...prevState.Weather5days];
    for(var i = 0; i < json.Forecasts.length; i++){
      newItems[i].date = json.Forecasts[i].Date;  
    }
    return {Weather5days: newItems};
  }
```

I used for loop here to save the date of all the parsed data from API to each array of Weather5days object. However, this is the error I get:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'newItems[i].date =
>   json.Forecasts[i].Date')

I'm not quite sure why. Maybe I declared the Weather5days object wrong, or should they be declared with a length in the first place? Thank you very much!

**UPDATE**
I've fiddled around with the code and in state I tried to declare Weather5days array as follows and it worked:

```
state = {
error: null,
temperature: null,
WeatherName: null,
isLoaded: false,
Weather5days: [{date:null},{date:null},{date:null},{date:null},{date:null}]
```

};

so all I did was literally create 5 array objects in the first place. I don't know why though. However this isn't really the solution as some circumstances I won't know the length of the array in the first place. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any guarantee that the size of `newItems` is the same as `json.Forecasts` ?

Comment: I see the json as a variable name, but did you really parse the response? `then(response => { response.json() }`

Comment: @Anas the size of newItems is referenced to Weather5days, as in the code const newItems = [...prevState.Weather5days]; so would this mean that newItems is also empty array object with unknown length?

Comment: @gazdagero  yep that part is fine I just skipped writing the code above .then()

Comment: The first step is to figure out what value is `undefined`. You can do this by adding `console.log()` lines in your code or using the debugger in your browser's development tools. For example, you can log `newItems` and `json` to see if they are what you expect. You can also log `json.Forecasts`. For more debugging tips read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: if `json.Forecasts.length` is > to `newItems.length`, then `newItems[i]` might be undefined.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Please see the updated information

Comment: @Anas Please see the updated information

Comment: Your state is initialized with `Weather5days: [{}]`, an array with one element. Then you copy the array in newItems and you read indexes greater than 0 - `newItems[i].date` that are out of bound in your for loop. Using a for loop in your use case is unsafe, you should use the Array's map method in order to return your new items : json.Forecasts.map((forecast, index) => ({} /* return your newItem */))

Comment: @Stouffi Please post that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your state was (before edit) initialized with `Weather5days: [{}]`, an array with one element. Then you copy the array in newItems and you read indexes greater than 0 using `newItems[i].date` that are out of bound in your for loop. Using a for loop in your use case is unsafe, you should use the Array's map method in order to return your new items : `json.Forecasts.map((forecast, index) => ({} /* return your newItem */))`

Comment: right that was the problem! I thought though the way to declare array with unknown length is var array = [] like this? If not, how would I declare array of object with unknown length and update the properties of the object in the state? Thank you

Comment: @hyuklee For initialization `state = {array: []}` is fine. Afterward whenever you update your state you should replace the entire array with the new items (object reference will change) instead of mutating directly the array. map method is perfect for this usage

Comment: so i did the following referring to your answer: 
.then(json =>{
var newArr = json.Forecasts.map(function(val) {
        return {
            date: val.Date,
        };
      });
}

this.setState({Weather5days: newArr})

There are no errors, however Weather5days does not get set to newArr. I've checked that data for newArr has been correctly copied from Forecasts, using console.log. For initialization, I have used state = {Weather5days: []}. I guess the problem is in the initialization, or this.setState({Weather5days: newArr})

Comment: If you log your render function which should be called soon after the setState call, does your state has expected Weather5days value (`this.state.Weather5days`) ?

Comment: nope, just consoles Array [] which prob means empty array. Funny thing is, if initialize Weather5days back to Weather5days:[{},{},{},{},{}] then it works again. So i guess the initialization is the problem. There must be a way to declare with unknown length hmm.

Comment: Maybe your component is more complex than that I thought. It will help if you insert the entire workflow of your component in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Using: import update from 'immutability-helper';

```
this.setState(prevState => update(prevState, {
    Weather5days: { $set: json.Forecasts}
})
```

Comment: Would this map each array of Forecasts to Weather5days, e.g. Forecast[0-5] to Weather5days[0-5]?

Comment: this will replace the array with the response from json